# Setup AEM in Eclipse and create a project

Tags: eclipse, aem

I am very new to AEM and I am trying to create a AEM project in Eclipse based on certain tutorials from internet.

After installing the AEM plugin by using this [url](https://eclipse.adobe.com/aem/dev-tools/), I tried to create the project. I tried different approaches - some of them failed.

**Approach - 1:**
Mars Eclipse, Java 1.8 and AEM 6.2
Select the Archetype-10, choose **Setup new server**, enter the server details and deploy it while creating the project, where I got an error "

> The server does not support version 2.4 of the J2EE Web module
>   specification.

**Approach - 2:**
Mars Eclipse, Java 1.8 and AEM 6.2
First create the AEM server in the server window
Select the Archetype-10, Choose Don't deploy on server, Finish. And then add these projects into the created AEM server. I was able to start the server and publish the projects, but its not reflected in the **apps** folder of AEM.
I am getting an error if I clicked **debug button** and the error is

> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException: Got status code 500 for call to http://localhost:4502/system/sling/tooling/sourceReferences.json

**Approach - 3:**
Luna Eclipse, Java 1.8 and AEM 6.2
I followed the steps in Approach-2. I could see the components published to apps folder of AEM. Again, I could not do debug. I am getting the same error. I could not find any useful materials related to this.

Please let me know where I am making a mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the same issue, but if you double click the server instance in eclipse. It opens up the details, on the right at the end there is a option for Debug. Expand it and uncheck the Resolve sources when connecting.
[image]
Restart the server in debug mode w/o error.

> Updates --

Also make sure that your AEM is running in the debug mode, you need to pass debug params to the JVM at start up -

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

Above 8000 is the debug port.

You can find more details [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQ5HowToSetupRemoteDebuggingWithEclipse.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. After I did, when I restarted in debug, I am getting the following error :"could not establish debug connection to localhost : 10147
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect". FYI, I h gave the debug port as 10147 in AEM server instance in eclipse.

Comment: Is your AEM running in debug mode and has the same debug port configured?
AEM to be started in debug mode by passing JVM parameters - -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=<debug port>,server=y,suspend=n

See my updates to the response

Comment: Hi Ameesh, thanks for your solution, it works like a charm. Out of my curiosity, do you have any idea what caused this issue? I don't have any issue on windows. I am able to get the json result from http://localhost:4502/system/sling/tooling/sourceReferences.json, but not on Mac.

Comment: @Vincent - From what I figured, the bundle org.apache.sling.tooling.support.source was missing in my instance, I installed it manually to get this servlet working.

Comment: @AmeeshTrikha, thanks for your hint. I did search this bundle, found it in my console, and it's active as well. The error I received was org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException: Got status code 500.

Answer (score 1):

Btw you can simply use a "-debug" flag with port number, instead of the lengthy -agentlib....

e.g

```
java -jar cq-quickstart-6.3.0.jar -r author -p 4502 -debug 30303
```