# How to connect to an AEM 6.2 server in from eclipse Mars in Debug mode

Tags: eclipse, aem

I have done the configuration as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup AEM in Eclipse and create a project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388879/setup-aem-in-eclipse-and-create-a-project)

Comment: Thanks Ameesh, reading the above post from my mobile, yes it does look like i should researched rather than creating a duplicate query, i will try the resolution you have shared on the original question and inform about results; Thanks nonetheless for swift responses.